# Integrate fb:comments with comments on Facebook page

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-integration

I use fb:comments on my website and I also have a Facebook Page. Is it possible that whenever a user posts a comment on a webpage in my site, the same comment gets posted on the Facebook's Page wall?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, you cannot control where a user decides to post his comment. This will negate comment ownership, the user did not authorize the website to post on the page wall *only* in the comments plugin.

You can however maybe include a Facebook tab with the fb:comments shown. If the fb:comments span more than one blog post then you may need to create your own app within the tab to handle this.