# Is it possible to extract comments from a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I wished to be able to pint my Facebook Comments plugin to my FB page instead of my website, I hoped that it was possible just by placing the FB page's URL in the plugin code, just as we do it for like buttons, anyway, I'm pretty sure [that's not possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/integrate-fbcomments-with-comments-on-facebook-page).

Now, I would like to know is there anyway to extract comments (not post comments) from a Facebook page and show them on a website? like a feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge the current API doesn’t allow for this. Privacy setting would also need to allow such extraction to take place.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is possible with some applications. Like tweets extraction from twitter, same happens with facebook